# Can I trigger an auto-negotiation of an interface using the ethtool userspace API with NETLINK sockets?

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, ioctl, netlink

I would like to replicate the behavior of `ethtool -r` when auto-negotiation is active in my C++ code with NETLINK sockets. I search the CLI `ethtool` [source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/ethtool/ethtool.git/tree/ethtool.c#n3435) and I found that they use IOCTL sockets and the command of ethtool `ETHTOOL_NWAY_RST`. According to kernel docs [here](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/ethtool-netlink.html#request-translation), this command has not been translated to NETLINK sockets. Before I give up, I just want know if there is another approach to get the same behavior.

#### What I tried so far

- I have static routes in the interface, so turning down and up the interface would not work because I lose those routes. This does not happen with `ethtool -r`.
- For the same reason the `ip link set down/up [dev]` behavior also would not be ideal in my case.

My code is currently working using the CLI of `ethtool`, but a more clean and better approach would be to use the userspace API directly. My code has already been made for NETLINK sockets and that's why I prefer this approach.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks